# "Хідник" -це діалектизм?

Tags: вживання-слів

Неодноразово чула слово "хідник (у значенні "ткана доріжка"). Це  діалектизм? Знайшла його у ["Словнику української мови"](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA):

> ХІДНИ́К, а́, ч., розм.
>   1. Те саме, що хід 4. — Під цією церквою викопано глибокий льох, і від нього ведуть чотири хідники до кожної башти (Стар., Облога.., 1961, 67); І ще скажу: таки ж довгенько він Копав хідник, дорогу до рятунку (Рильський, Марина, 1944, 43); Вони [шкідники] підгризають коріння молодих дерев, об’їдають листя й кору, прокладають під корою хідники (Рад. Укр., 21.IX 1946, 3); // гірн. Горизонтальна або похила виробка для переміщення шахтарів. Зараз же біля сторчової шахти пробивано новий хідник (Гр., І, 1963, 367).
>
> 2. Те саме, що хід 5. Йдуть усі троє: він, Шарлота й Мундзьо. Вже на хіднику, що провадить на веранду (Март., Тв., 1954, 300); — Геть,— заявив я категорично, вказуючи рукою на хідник.— Геть, і забудь сюди дорогу (Чаб., Катюша, 1960, 139).
> 3. Піднята вище проїжджої частини пішохідна стежка з асфальту, цегли, дощок і т. ін. по боках вулиці чи площі; тротуар. Серед вулиці стояла калюжа, а там, де мали б бути хідники, росло будяччя (Крим., Вибр., 1965, 352); Незабаром ми йшли вже тільки вдвох по стемнілій вулиці, по м’яких дерев’яних хідниках попід стінами білих будинків (Перв., Материн.. хліб, 1960, 26); Він схилив голову; попід ногами — вичовганий цегляний хідник, порепана міська земля (Жур., Нам тоді.., 1968, 88); // рідко. Стежка в саду, парку; алея. На другий день пігнали [погнали] нас, може, двадцять парубків, у панський сад,— бач, захотів пан в саду кручених хідників (Фр., XIII, 1954, 109).
> 4. Вузький, довгий килим або товста тканина такої ж форми, що її стелять на підлогу; постілка, доріжка. Зробив [Бронко] кілька гімнастичних вправ на «турніку», на якому мама тріпала хідники (Вільде, III, 1968, 120); Червоні хідники й перські килими прикривали підлогу, викладену з різнокольорових камінних плит (Панч, III, 1956, 54); М’яким хідником наблизилась [Ганна] до стола, якийсь час постояла біля нього (Д. Бедзик, Серце.., 1961, 93).
>
> Словник української мови: в 11 тт. / АН УРСР. Інститут мовознавства; за ред.І. К. Білодіда. — К.: Наукова думка, 1970—1980. — Т. 11. — С. 72.
>
> Хідник, ка, м. Дорожка, тропинка. Вх. Уг. 273.
>   Словарь української мови: в 4-х тт. / За ред. Б. Грінченка. — К., 1907—1909. — Т. 4. — С. 400.

І теж слово у ["Лексиконі львівському"](http://slovopedia.org.ua/101/53413/1068027.html):

> хідник
>   хідни́к 1. тротуар (ст): Хлопець не йшов на Ринок, він тільки здалеку бачив, як збирається товпа на хідниках, як гудять вівати, як зриваються з голов капелюхи (Лисяк)2. килимова або ткана доріжка (ср, ст): Найбільше не люблю у прибиранні – тріпати хідники (Авторка); На сходах постелено червоні хідники. По цих сходах сюди й туди ходили професори (Шухевич)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У згаданому Вами [Словнику української мови 1970-1980 рр.](http://sum.in.ua/s/khidnyk) бачимо, що є мітка “розм”:

> **ХІДНИ́К**, а, чол., розм.

Отже, лексема використовується лише у розмовному стилі, у науковому його НЕ вживають.

У [Словнику Лемківскої Говірки. Пиртей П.С. . 2001.](https://ukrainian_lemko.academic.ru/14427/%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA) подають таку статтю:

> **Хідник**, -ника, ч. Пр. Тротуар.

Отже, якщо і Словник Лемківської Говірки, і Лексикон Львівський подають, що це слово належить до говірки, а також і СУМ-11 подає мітку "розм", робимо висновок, що слово "хідник" - це діалектизм і може використовуватись у розмовному стилі.